# Use git-svn with an existing repo lacking .git/svn/

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I've cloned a project's sources using Git, which is converted on the server from a SVN repo. The problem with this Git repository is that it lacks tags, branches, and some revisions are missing. The number of revisions is enormous (~20000) for me to use git-svn clone, and it'd be a waste of bandwidth and time as I already have most objects in my local repo. Because of this, I'd like to know:

- How can I convert my Git repository to a git-svn repo to update directly from the SVN repo instead of the broken Git repo.
- Can I fetch the missing revisions without having to clone everything?
- Is it possible to download tags with Git directly?
- Will those branches be an extra problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Letting git-SVN take over your clone is easy; just run `git svn init` with the same arguments you used in the original repo and then your `git svn fetch` should find the existing commits in the repo.
- Adding the branches can't be done without serious repo surgery: you'd have to rewrite much of your history to include the cross-branch merges.
- Pulling tags in is easy and I believe can be done after the initial repo clone.